# Space counting in expl3 is strange

Tags: expl3

The function `\str_count_spaces:n{}` should count the number of spaces in its parameter.

For me it outputted unexpected results.

```
\str_count_spaces:n{he llo} %->0
```

However these were okay,

```
\str_count_spaces:n{he\ llo} %->1
\str_count_spaces:n{he~llo} %->1
\str_count_spaces:n{he\char{32}llo} %->1
```

Did I misunderstand the definition of this function?

Comment: In expl3 syntax a usual space is not a space token but ignored. So usual spaces are only counted, if the argument is not read in expl3 catcode context. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132030/277964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you misunderstood the concept of strings in expl3.

> A TeX string (and thus an expl3 string) is a series of characters which have category
> code 12 (“other”) with the exception of space characters which have category code 10
> (“space”). Thus at a technical level, a TeX string is a token list with the appropriate
> category codes. In this documentation, these are simply referred to as strings.

There's a problem: to understand what this means you need to understand what "token" in TeX means,
which ultimately boils down to reading TeXbook etc.... ([resources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/250119))

Anyway, so `\char` or `\`  are not **character tokens**, but all the `str` function converts
its arguments to string. You can view what the string will be with `\str_show:n`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_show:n{he\ llo}
\str_show:n{he~llo}
\str_show:n{he\char{32}llo}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
he\ llo
he llo
he\char {32}llo
```

Because of how `\detokenize` primitive works in eTeX (the behavior is inherited from whatever function used to implement converting token list to string in TeX source code,
in expl3 documentation it's mentioned that the conversion is done with `\tl_to_str:n` where the description of `\detokenize`
is copied there) a space is added after `\char`, which has nothing to do with the fact that the number is 32 and it typesets
a space when run normally.

Comment: In retrospect, as a formal language description expl3 documentation abstracts away the TeX details reasonably well, but it doesn't do a good job at *teaching* the language and leave the readers in the dark on why some commands' behavior (e.g. [f-type expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494280/250119)) are highly counterintuitive (answer: they're inherited from the corresponding TeX primitives which there's no (or no efficient) way to abstract it out) (not to complain, it's difficult.)

Comment: `interface3` is intended as a reference, we don't yet have 'Programming in `expl3`' (and would be very happy to have a volunteer to write it!)

Answer (score 5):

Within `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` all spaces are ignored.

To insert an explicit space use `~` (which as you note works).

You can create a LaTeX command that wraps the `expl3` macro to count spaces in a non-strange way outside of of the Expl3 programming environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \CountSpaces { m }
  {
    \str_count_spaces:n { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\CountSpaces{he llo} % -> 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: So would ```\str_if_eq:nnTF{~}{#1}{yes}{no}``` be correct in a function judging whether its parameter is a space? I'm going to use it after ```\ExplSyntaxOff```.

Comment: @youthdoo If the "function" that uses `\str_if_eq:nnTF` and `~` is defined with ExplSyntax On, `~` **is** a space and is equal to a literal space on the user-level. (Outside ExplSyntax `~` is an unbreakable space which is not the same as a space.)